# Multiply a Pandas DF Column (Float) against a Column (Int) with negative values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, calculated-columns

I've been trying to understand a issue I've been having for about 2 hours now and I'm not getting anywhere. I have a DataFrame with multiple columns, two of which are 'Conversor' which is dtype Float and 'Qty in UnE' which is dtype Integer with some negative values.

I'm trying to multiply these two columns to get the result in a new third columns via code:

```
df['Qte'] = df['Conversor'] * df['Qty in UnE']
```

It seems to work well, however, some cases where the decimal is to small, for instance 0.000006 and in multiplies by value -1, it returns 6000000 in the new column and I can't for the life of me understand why. Here is a screen of the excel file generated from this DF:

```
           Qte  Conversor  Qty in UnE
0   6000000.00   0.000006          -1
1        60.00  10.000000          -6
2        10.00  10.000000          -1
3        40.00  40.000000          -1
4        10.00  10.000000          -1
5       902.40  30.080000         -30
6         0.05   0.050000          -1
7        10.00  10.000000          -1
8        90.00  10.000000          -9
9        10.00  10.000000          -1
10        0.05   0.050000          -1
11  5000000.00   0.000005          -1
```

df.info()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 2044 entries, 0 to 2043
Data columns (total 5 columns):

```
 #   Column                Non-Null Count  Dtype
---  ------                --------------  -----
 0  Qty in UnE            2044 non-null   int32
 1  %                     1328 non-null   object
 2  UM                    1328 non-null   object
 3  Conversor             2044 non-null   float64
 4  Qte                   2044 non-null   float64
```

dtypes: float64(2), int32(1), object(2)
memory usage: 327.5+ KB
None

The row:
[1 rows x 5 columns]

```
Qty in UnE                                   -1
%                                           100
UM                                            L
Conversor                              0.000006
Qte                                   -6000000.00
```

Name: 8, dtype: object

The value in the new columns is positive because I have already treated it. If you look at the first and last line, the values are incorrect, however the other ones seems to all be correct.

I just wish to understand why this is happening :/

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Could you do df.info() and see what could be happening? Also, it could be a formatting thing, too. Just a hunch. Creating this df from scratch, I'm getting the right outputs, so I assume it has something to do with a datatype mismatch or how the df is displayed. Could you also maybe try iterating over the rows of the output and printing to see what's coming out?

Comment: as @Matt indicated, I also was able to get the correct result when I created your dataframe from scratch

Comment: Hi @Matt, I've included the information you requested... Do you believe it might have something to do with 'Qty in UnE' being int32?

Comment: @Hawk I'm still able to get the right results from just the data you're showing here. In top of that, I have the same data type you have. When you multiple a float by int in pandas, it should automatically convert it to another float. My first thought was maybe some type of weird underflow or something, but this just seems bizarre.

Are you importing this from somewhere? Maybe that could be the issue?